# jQuery/JS - как привязать к каждой кнопке соответствующее pop-up окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть кнопки:

```
<button id="btn-1" class="about-btn">About</button>
<button id="btn-2" class="about-btn">About</button>
...и так планируется в будущем N кнопок создать...
<button id="btn-N" class="about-btn">About</button>
```

При клике на каждую кнопку должно всплывать соответствующее кнопке (btn-N) pop-up окно.

Код поп-апов:

```
<div id="btn-1-popup" class="pop-up">
   <p>текст поп-апа №1</p>
   <button class="close">X</button>
</div>

...и так у каждой кнопки есть своё окно с уникальным текстом...

<div id="btn-N-popup" class="pop-up">
   <p>текст поп-апа №N</p>
   <button class="close">X</button>
</div>
```

И вот, например, при клике на #btn-1 появится окошко #btn-1-popup, при клике на #btn-2 появится окошко #btn-2-popup и тд для N добавленных кнопок. Также в каждом поп-апе есть кнопка закрыть.

Подключил jQuery для этого:

```
$("#btn-1").click(function() {
    $("#btn-1-popup").addClass("visible");
});
$("#btn-1 .close").click(function() {
    $("#btn-1-popup").removeClass("visible");
});

...и так к каждой кнопке свой поп-ап...

$("#btn-N").click(function() {
    $("#btn-N-popup").addClass("visible");
});
$("#btn-N .close").click(function() {
    $("#btn-N-popup").removeClass("visible");
});
```

А вот если у меня будет много таких кнопок на сайте, например за 50 шт., и к каждой отдельно в jQuery надо прописывать целый блок кода.

Вопрос: как автоматизировать код jQuery или на JS подобное можно реализовать чтобы прописать по шаблону один раз и всё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.about-btn').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id + '-popup').show();
});

$('.pop-up .close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Вот и весь шаблон